# If $I$ is a proper ideal not prime, there exists $J,K$ such that $J\subsetneq I$, $K\subsetneq I$ and $JK\subseteq I$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noetherian

Let $R$ be a ring and $I\neq R$ an ideal. Suppose $I$ is not prime. Prove there exist ideals $J,K$ such that $I\subsetneq J$, $I\subsetneq K$ and $JK\subseteq I$.

I saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594438/proper-ideal-i-implies-exists-prime-ideals-p-i-such-that-p-1-cdots-p-n) where the OP mentions the result I'm trying to prove but I couldn't find any actual proof on this site or any books online.

I have proven a similar result, which goes as follows:

Let $J,K$ be ideals and let $I$ be a prime ideal such that $JK\subseteq I$. Then, $J\subseteq I$ or $K\subseteq I$.

*Proof*:

Suppose $J\subsetneq I$. There exists $y\in J, y\notin I$. For every $x\in K$, $xy\in JK\subseteq I$. Since $I$ is prime, either $x\in I$ or $y\in I$. Hence, $x\in I$ and we have $K\subseteq I$. $\square$

It somehow feels like one is a contraposition of the other (idk if I'm using the correct term as english is not my main language), but I can't exactly see how to make the jump.

Is there a way to prove the first statement directly without needing to lean on the second one or use a contraposition argument?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ be such that $xy \in I$ with neither $x$ or $y$ in I.  Since I is not prime then such an $x$ and $y$ must exist.  Let $J = (I, x)$ and $K = (I, y)$.  Then $JK \subset I$.

Comment: Is $JK\subset I$ because $J\cap K=I$?  I've never used the notation $(I,x)$, I imagine it's the same as $I+(x)$.

Comment: $(I, x)$ is the ideal generated by $x$ and $I$.  $JK \subset I$ because each element of $JK$ is a sum of elements of $I$ and elements of the form $r x y$ with $r$ in the ring.  I’m assuming the ring is commutative.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!